# What class/interface should I work with for a PowerPoint picture & chart?

Tags: powerpoint, office-interop

This is all using the COM (not VSTO) interop API into PowerPoint.

If I am working with a selected Table, I use the Table interface. For text in a textbox I use a TextRange.

What should I use for a picture, the Shape object representing it? Or is there something better?

Same question for a chart?

Comment: Whoever voted this down - why? I'm asking what is the class/interface that is commonly used - which is key to using the API right.

Comment: In the PowerPoint object model, pictures are Shapes (in most cases), so you'd use the Shape object. Charts are also shapes (usually of .Type=3, at least in recent versions of PPT).

Comment: @SteveRindsberg thank you. If you post that as an answer I'm happy to accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the PowerPoint object model, pictures are Shapes (in most cases), so you'd use the Shape object. Charts are also shapes (usually of .Type=3, at least in recent versions of PPT).

Actually, pretty much everything on a slide is a Shape of one .Type or another.